# Matrix indexing error in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I keep getting this error in Matlab:

> Attempted to access r(0,0); index must be a positive integer or
>   logical.
>
> Error in ==> Romberg at 15

I ran it with `Romberg(1.3, 2.19,8)`

I think the problem is the statement is not logical because I made it positive and still got the same error. Anyone got some ideas of what i could do?

```
function Romberg(a, b, n)
    h = b - a;
    r = zeros(n,n);
    for i = 1:n
        h = h/2;
        sum1 = 0;

        for k = 1:2:2^(i)
            sum1 = sum1 + f(a + k*h);
        end

        r(i,0) = (1/2)*r(i-1,0) + (sum1)*h;

        for j = 1:i
            r(i,j) = r(i,j-1) + (r(i,j-1) - r(i-1,j-1))/((4^j) - 1);
        end
    end
    disp(r);
end

function f_of_x = f(x)
    f_of_x = sin(x)/x;
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two lines where you're using 0 to index, which you can't in Matlab:

```
r(i,0) = (1/2)*r(i-1,0) + (sum1)*h;
```

and

```
r(i,j) = r(i,j-1) + (r(i,j-1) - r(i-1,j-1))/((4^j) - 1);
```

when j==1 or i==1.

I suggest that you run your loops starting from 2, and replace the exponents i and j with (i-1) and (j-1), respectively.

As an aside: You could write the loop

```
for k = 1:2:2^(i)

   sum1 = sum1 + f(a + k*h);

end
```

as

```
k = 1:2:2^i;
tmp = f(a + k*h);
sum1 = sum(tmp);
```

if you write f_of_x as

```
sin(x)./x
```

Comment: In case `a` is ever negative, you might want to define `f(x)` as
`f_of_x = sin(x)./x; f_of_x(isnan(f_of_x)) = 1;`  Or `sinc(x/pi)` would work too.

Answer (score 3):

In MATLAB, vectors and matrices are indexed starting from 1.  Therefore, the very first line of your code is invalid because the index on `r` is 0.

Comment: Sorry about that was typo i did not mean to put that first line of code in there.

Comment: Nevertheless, the same line exists in the middle of the code block.  It's trying to assign to `r(i, 0)` which is illegal because 0 is an illegal index into the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You have zero subscripts in

```
r(i,0) = (1/2)*r(i-1,0) + (sum1)*h;
```

This is impossible in MATLAB -- all indices start form 1.